# Export SQL --> PostGIS + visualization in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am a newby in GIS and I need help to implement some functions...
I have an application (H2O facility) that works with a SQL database. I have entities like clients, measure devices, worksheets, etc, that have a geographical position (Lat, Long).
My idea is export this info to a GIS Database (PostGIS) and visualize it with QGIS. For example, visualize the water measure device layer o other layers in the street map.
How can I do this?

Comment: What do u call a 'SQL' database ?